# TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' differences

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am a new web developer learning JavaScript and I have been taking online courses, so please forgive me.

Can anyone explain to me why I get this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add'** when writing code in this order:

```
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
if (!audio) return;
audio.currentTime=0;
audio.play();

console.log(key);
key.classlist.add('playing');
```

But it works fine when written this way:

```
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
if (!audio) return;
key.classList.add('playing');
audio.currentTime = 0;
audio.play();
```

Comment: You have a typo - `key.classlist.add('playing');` - it should be `classList`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the culprit is a simple typo. In your first example,

`key.classlist.add('playing');` <-- the correct spelling is `classList` (capital L)

Can you try updating to `classList` and see if that resolves the issue?

Keep in mind that Javascript is a case-sensitive language. And as a suggestion, try to use a smart IDE, such as [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which can help you spot and debug such problems quite effectively.

---

To expand, the message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '[x]'` is essentially Javascript's equivalent of `null reference exception` present in most programming languages. What your Javascript parser is complaining about there is that it wasn't able to find the `.add` property on the `.classlist` property of `key`. Here's how it got there:

On the line `key.classlist.add('playing')`, it started parsing from left to right:

- `key` is known, great moving on.
- `classlist` (with typo) is unknown. At this point, Javascript will evaluate `key.classlist` to a unique value called `undefined`. Simply meaning that this property wasn't found on the object, ergo, it's undefined. Ok, keep parsing...
- Now it hits `key.classlist.add` and this is where things break down. This is equal to `undefined.add`. Now, this is an exception at this point, generating that message that you saw.

Since you're just getting started with Javascript, it would be worthwhile to read up and understand Javascript's unique/quirky `null` and `undefined` values and how they behave:

- `undefined`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined
- `null`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null